# Bit masks for subsets from two different sets

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have two sets -

set1 - {i1,i2,i3...iN1}

set2 - {k1,k2,k3...kN2}

For any single set of n items I can represent all possible subsets using bit masks 0-2^n -1.
Similarly how can i represent -

All possible subset of set1 and set2, where at-least 1 items is from the different set.

for example
{i1,i2,k1} is valid

but {i1,i2} - invalid as it has no item from set2.

I am trying to generate two things -

1. Kind of a equation which can give me a count of all subsets, like we have 2^n subsets for a single n items set.
2. Bit encoding/masks using which i can represent above type of subsets.

Comment: Are the sets disjoint?

Comment: No, they can have common numbers.

Comment: @G.D to be clear about the problem so if one set A has = {1,2,3} and B has = {2} and my final set has 1 from A and 3 from B and so the final set will look like - {1,3} , will this be considered a valid subset according to the provided constraints ?

Comment: @zenwraight yes, its just that atleast 1 item should exist in the second set, otherwise its no longer a subset of both sets.

Comment: @DanielWagner- Does it become easier to solve if set1, set2 are disjoint sets?

Comment: @G.D ya it they are disjoint sets then it becomes very easy because then it comes down to an easy combinatorics  problem ...

Comment: any limit on the size of n ?

Comment: @marvel308- the problem which i was solving had a dataset where both N1 and N2 were <=100.

Comment: Ha ha ha the input is so less @marvel308 you can go for an exponential time complexity also ... just kidding

Answer (score 0):

This will be easier if we introduce a few extra sets of interest. Let's call the two input sets S1 and S2; we'll define sets L, C, and R (for left, center, and right). Think of these as being the Venn diagram. So, define L = S1 \ S2, the elements in S1 that aren't in S2 at all; C = S1 ∩ S2, the elements that are in both S1 and S2, and R = S2 \ S1. Let's also write l, c, and r for the sizes of these sets, respectively.

Now we're ready to answer question 1: how many subsets of S1 ∪ S2 have an element from S1 and have an element from S2? There are two cases to consider: either we have a subset with an element in C (which satisfies both the "an element from S1" and the "an element from S2" clauses), or we have no elements in C and at least one each from L and R. In the first case, there are (2^c - 1) non-empty subsets of C, and 2^(l+r) subsets of the remainder, so there are (2^c - 1)*2^(l+r) sets in that case. In the second case, there are 2^l - 1 non-empty subsets of L and 2^r - 1 non-empty subsets of R, so there are (2^l - 1) * (2^r - 1) subsets in that case. Adding up the two cases, we have a total of 2^(c+l+r) - 2^l - 2^r total subsets satisfying the condition.

If you have a fancy representation of non-empty subsets, this also immediately suggests a data structure for storing these: a single bit tag for which case you're in, plus the appropriate representations of subsets and non-empty subsets in each case.

But I would probably just use a single bitmask of size c+l+r, even though there are a few "invalid" bitmasks: it's very compact, it's easy to check validity, and there are many cheap operations on bitmasks.